# trying to add numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a program to decrypt a encrypted message. The encrypted message is a very long set of numbers ".296.294.255.268.313.278.311.270.290.305.322.252.276.286.301.305.264.301.251.269.274.311.304.
230.280.264.327.301.301.265.287.285.306.265.282.319.235.262.278.249.239.284.237.249.289.250.
282.240.256.287.303.310.314.242.302.289.268.315.264.293.261.298.310.242.253.299.278.272.333.
272.295.306.276.317.286.250.272.272.274.282.308.262.285.326.321.285.270.270.241.283.305.319.
246.263.311.299.295.315.263.304.279.286.286.299.282.285.289.298.277.292.296.282.267.245.....ect". 
Each character of the message is transformed into three different numbers (eg.first character of message is '230 .280 .264' second character is '.327.301.265' ect).
so i am trying to use javascript to add the groups of three numbers and then save them as their own variable. thanks

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `msg` has that string in it, this will split it up and add the triplets together.

```
const [, triplets] = msg
  .split('.')
  .slice(1)
  .map(v => +v)
  .reduce(([count, list], val, i) => {
    if ((i + 1) % 3) return [count + val, list];
    return [val, list.concat(count)];
}, [0, []]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how the data is transmitted.    It looks like you could bring the data in as a string (or parse it into a string) and then use the split method to create an array of all of your numbers.

```
var numbers = "234.345.456.567"
var arr = numbers.split(".")
```

You would then loop over the array doing whatever you need for every set of three

```
var newArray[]
var i
for(i = 0; i < length; i += 3){
    //Add values here
    //Parse back to int
    newArray.push("sum Value")
}
```

Hope this was along the lines of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match all groups of three, then `map` each group to the number by splitting the string by `.`s and adding the 3 together:

```js
const input = '296.294.255.268.313.278.311.270.290.305.322.252.276.286.301.305.264.301.251.269.274.311.304. 230.280.264.327.301.301.265.287.285.306.265.282.319.235.262.278.249.239.284.237.249.289.250. 282.240.256.287.303.310.314.242.302.289.268.315.264.293.261.298.310.242.253.299.278.272.333. 272.295.306.276.317.286.250.272.272.274.282.308.262.285.326.321.285.270.270.241.283.305.319. 246.263.311.299.295.315.263.304.279.286.286.299.282.285.289.298.277.292.296.282.267.245';
const groupsOfThree = input.match(/\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\./g);
const sums = groupsOfThree.map((group) => {
  const nums = group.split('.').map(Number);
  return nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2];
});
console.log(sums);
```

Comment: When answers work for you, you can upvote them if they are helpful and Accept them if they solve your problem.